# Set cell value based on two other cell values in excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to determine how to go about setting the value of cell E3 based on the values in both cells C3 and D3.  For example if cell C3 is X024832069 and D3 is BUFF/BRIGHT DIP CLEAR ANODIZE E3 should be set to X10-15270A.

Cell C3 has 7 different part numbers available to choose from while cell D3 has 3 options available based on which part number is selected. Cell E3 has 21 different outcomes based on what is selected in C3 and D3.

[Excel Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iutjD.png)

Would I need to string together 21 IF statements or is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?

```
=IF(C3="X024832069",IF(D3="BUFF/BRIGHT DIP CLEAR ANODIZE","X10-15270A"))
```

Comment: Create a table with the 21 different combinations concatenated `X024832069BUFF/BRIGHT DIP CLEAR ANODIZE` with a second column column as their desired output then use VLOOKUP.

Comment: in that case it would be better to have a 2D table to my eye ... then index match row and column... also that would be easier to extend if needed later on...

Comment: @DirkReichel great idea.  I was trying to avoid the multiple match array formula and yours does that.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am not sure if that is sarcasm or not...

Comment: @DirkReichel no it was true admiration to a great thought.  Much better than mine.  I tend to think in database format as that is what I am dealing with currently and forget that excel can move left and right as well as up and down.

Comment: @ScottCraner oh ok... I still have quite a few problems with the English language... sorry for the misunderstanding ^o^;

Comment: @DirkReichel glad you asked.

Comment: I ended up concatenating my combinations and did a VLOOKUP.  Thanks for your help guys!